# How to clean such a bad shapefile for routing?

Tags: postgis, qgis, shapefile, pgrouting

I am trying to clean a shapefile to make it usable for routing with pgrouting, postgis, postgresql.

Here an intersection, it seems to be connected but when we zoom …. It is not:

[image: not zoomed 1] 
[image: zoomed 1]

Same here :

[image: not zoomed 2]
[image: zoomed 2]

Here (it is zoomed at max) there is 2 ways when it seems to be one, and only one is connected :

[image: zoomed at max 2]

I am using assign_vertex_id with different tolerances, and QGIS and PostGIS, but I don't know what to use in it.

Comment: I wonder: are these truly errors?  For instance, both situations could be used to represent a two-way street meeting a one-way street.  This may be a critical issue, because you don't want to introduce new errors in an effort to eliminate others!

Comment: In fact it is just an horribly bad shapefile, I want an extremely simple undirected routing, and what you see is very zoomed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use GRASS to do some cleaning. I think you need to break those vectors remove duplicates and then snap them. For that there is the [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.clean.html) tool with the options `break, rmdupl and snap` .

Answer (score 4):

Within PostGIS, try [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to snap vertices to a virtual grid. You need to to some detective work to determine what snapping distance to use. It could be a 0.01 (1 cm), or 1.0, etc.