# pgrouting unexpected output

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, indoor

Thats my [ways.shp file](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1394413789). I loaded this to PostgreSQL DB using PostGIS shape file loader. I ran pgr_anlayzeGraph() on it and found it had a lot of isolated segments.

Next I ran pgr_nodeNetwork() to create a new table 'ways_ways'.
I made the topology  for it and ran the following query in Qgis sql window.

```
 SELECT * FROM ways_ways JOIN (SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM 
pgr_astar('SELECT id, source, target, cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM ways_ways', 
1, 108, false, false) )AS route ON ways_ways.id = route.node;
```

Given below are the screenshots:
Original floorplan and the prescribed route
[image: 1]
query ouput
[image: 2]

Clearly , I don't have a continuous output. I ran pgr_analyseGraph on ways_ways to find that it has no more isolated segments . It has 51 deadends, which is acceptable.

1. Did I miss any step in pgrouting?
2. Is there anyway to see which node has id 1 and id 108 in qgis?
3. i ran the same query in another map(which i downloaded) and got output for all possible source and target ids. So how can i create a way(a route) that is completely noded?

Comment: I created the shp file using JOSM

Comment: If you want to share a shapefile, you have to zip all files and upload it on a file sharing service.

Comment: [i have uploaded the shapefiles here. please check it](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1394413789)

Answer (score 2):

Your network is not routable. For a routable network, you have to split/break all edges where they intersect. Otherwise pgrouting cannot create a usable topology. This also explains why you got the error about isolated segments.

[image]

Possible solutions to split edges include:
[Split edges at intersections in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13544/split-edges-at-intersections-in-postgis) or [How to clean such a bad shapefile for routing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-to-clean-such-a-bad-shapefile-for-routing/12912#12912) (especially v.clean break).

Comment: how can i break the edges?

Comment: After 2 weeks of agony, I have successfully implemented pgrouting on my map. Thanks a lot underdark.

All i had to do was open my shp file in GRASS GUI and use the v.clean option to break the segments and export it as a new shpfile.