# How to set the tolerance value in pgr_createTopology function of pgrouting?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, topology

I am making a map based on the floor plan of a building. 
I made the shapefile and added it to the PostgreSQL database.

I created the topology for the map using the following code:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

The tolerance provided here is 0.00001. I didn't get many vertices when I checked it up (just 14). How can I set a proper tolerance value? What does it depend on?

Answer (score 2):

The tolerance value is in the same unit as your geometry. 
When the distance between start/end point of two linestring geometries is smaller than the tolerance, then the topology function assumes, that these two points are connected.
This means, both points get snapped together.

The unit of the tolerance value is in most cases either `meter` or `degree`, which usually makes a big difference.

In your case, if the projection unit would be meter, then 2 points must be very very close to make a connection between the road segments.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is of a different nature since your network is not routable as explained in [pgrouting unexpected output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89038/pgrouting-unexpected-output)

dkastl already explained how it would work if your input data was correct.

Comment: ok. I understand

Answer (score -2):

For those like me who want a more direct answer : If your are using SRS WGS84 (EPSG:4326), try with the following link : http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/wgs84_180/intptW.html

At the time of writing, it is a tool to convert degrees to meters or feet. I didn't find the reverse, meters to degrees. But it can help you to guess the famous "tolerance" parameter for functions like "pgr_createTopology". Normally you have degrees for latitude, and degrees for longitude. But this parameter looks like to use the same value for both.

If the Web site is no longer available, I hope somebody will post a simple formula for us, computer programmers.

Don't forget it depends on the coordinate system you are using.

EDIT: The tolerance is the maximal distance between two points to be considered the same point. It depends greatly on the quality of your data set. I'm myself searching the better value for OpenStreetMap. For the moment, I'm using "0.001" with WGS84.

EDIT: If you read the comments, "mkennedy" say the link is not what I was thinking. I'm sorry. If somebody has a formula, or a better link, please reply to this thread, or add a comment.

Comment: I wrote this reply just because nobody is able to help those who are faced like me to work with degrees, a *meaningless* unit of measure.

Comment: "Go 2 degrees 4 minutes 30 second North-West" and you will find a convenience store." My God !!!!

Comment: Should I ask him what is his SRS :)

Comment: The NGA link you posted calculates the geoid-ellipsoid separation. It's nothing to do with converting between degrees and meters as 'horizontal' distances.

Comment: Do you have a formula, or another link ?

Comment: This is straying from the original question...A rough conversion from degrees-to-meters is that for WGS84/GRS80 at the equator, 1 deg = 111319.49 m. A degree along a meridian is about the same distance at any latitude. A degree along a parallel is shorter by cos(latitude). So 60N, 55660 m.

Comment: Thanks. This is not really straying from the original question because we have to provide a "tolerance" in degrees. If we know approximately the tolerance in meters, we need a way to convert to degrees. Sure, it can't be precise, but we have to provide one and only one value in degrees regardless the latitude/longitude. I've tried to get this value from the data provider (OSM), but with no luck. So we are all guessing !